# Adding user defined templates to Tex Works

Tags: texworks, workflow

I'm using TexWorks on Mac. I have a good template that I want to add to TexWorks so that I can use it simply by clicking File > New From Template. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `~/Library/TeXworks/` there you'll find the folder `templates` where you can create a folder containing your personal templates.